# C# MySql.Data. How to parse a MySql Table to a List<T>

Tags: c#, mysql, list

I am developing a application to read records from a MySql Data Base. I want to read all records and parte then to a list .

This is my code:

```
 var command = DatabaseConnection.MySql_Connection.CreateCommand();
 command.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM Words";
 var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();
 _records = (List<Words>)reader.OfType<Words>();
```

But the error is

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'd__61`1[MySql02Net.Words]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MySql02Net.Words]'.'

Someone can help me?
Regards

Comment: AFAIK there's nothing out of the box for this,you need to use an object mapper such as [Dapper](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper), then you could use something like `DatabaseConnection.MySql_Connection.Query<Words>("SELECT * FROM Words");`

Answer (score 2):

OfType returns an IEnumerable, not a list. Something like this ought to work:

```cs
var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();
_records = reader.OfType<Words>().ToList();
```

Comment: `OfType` won't do any custom conversions though, so the resulting list will be empty since MySqlDataReader doesn't enumerate `Words` it enumerates `DbDataRecord`. The following would yield results `_records = _reader.OfType<DbDataRecord>();`. You still need some kind of data mapper or conversion to convert from a reader to a custom class

Comment: @GarethD: Thanks. I thought it would do some simple mapping. Since it doesn't Dapper would definitely be my choice.